# Howto setup Internet Connection Sharing with static IPs

Tags: windows-7, static-ip, connection-sharing

I got the following setup:

One client Windows-PC with a fixed IP 10.0.0.10, one Host with 2 LAN adapters (fixed 10.0.0.20 and DHCP 192.168.0.xxx). I'd like to share the network connection of the host with the client:

[image]

I already did find out about Internet Connection Sharing and how to change some of the configuration via the registry (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230148), but I could not manage to get it setup correctly. Is it possible to configure ICS to keep the static IP adresses on the connection between client and host? What values would be required for `StandaloneDhcpAddress` and `ScopeAdress`?

Comment: The directions on the page you linked to are the instructions to do exactly that.

Comment: I could not figure out how... which values are needed for the two registry keys? Can I still keep the static IPs on Host & Client?

Comment: The instructions mention no reason you cannot use a static ip address if you want.